# OWL java use same data property for two classes

Tags: java, owl

I am working with OWL and I have defined 2 classes and they share a data propertie:

```
<Declaration>
    <DataProperty IRI="#hasLastName" />
</Declaration>

<DataPropertyDomain>
    <DataProperty IRI="#hasLastName" />
    <Class IRI="#Class1" />
</DataPropertyDomain>

<DataPropertyDomain>
    <DataProperty IRI="#hasLastName" />
    <Class IRI="#Class2" />
</DataPropertyDomain>
```

In java I have created a project that starting from an owl file and an xml file it creates a form.
in my xml file I define the sections of the form in this way:

```
<section>
        <iri>http://www.sample.com/myontology#class1</iri>
        <infoList>
            <info type="text" property="http://www.sample.com/myontology#hasLastName" required="true" />
            <info type="text" property="http://www.sample.com/myontology#hasFirstName" required="true" />
            <info type="text" property="http://www.sample.com/myontology#hasEmail" required="false" />
            <info type="text" property="http://www.sample.com/myontology#hasPhone" required="false" />
        </infoList>
</section>


<section>
        <iri>http://www.sample.com/myontology#class2</iri>
        <infoList>
            <info type="text" property="http://www.sample.com/myontology#hasLastName" required="true" />
            <info type="text" property="http://www.sample.com/myontology#hasUser" required="false" />
            <info type="text" property="http://www.sample.com/myontology#hasRole" required="false" />
        </infoList>
</section>
```

How can I access the different Last name Properties for class 1 and class 2?
I retrieve it by http://www.sample.com/myontology#hasLastName
There is something like http://www.sample.com/myontology#Class1#hasLastName ?

Sorry I am a very beginner with Ontology and it is not very clear to me

Comment: ehm, this sounds more like *"how to query XML data in Java?"* Either traverse the DOM, or use XPath resp. XQuery

Comment: No, I am able to query the xml and to retrieve the data, I want to know if there is a way to get the OWL property of a defined class. I use the same property for two classes.

Comment: It will depend on what API you are using to read the OWL file. What API are you using?

Comment: I am using OWL API

Comment: And now, just use the methods of the OWL API. By the way, the expression *property of a class* is misleading. A class does not have a property.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an ontology as follows:

```
Datatype: xsd:string

DataProperty: hasLastName
    Domain: 
        Person,
        Student

    Range: 
        xsd:string        

Class: Person

Class: Student
```

the following code will retrieve the 2 domains:

```
IRI lastNamePropertyIRI = IRI.create(ontologyIRI + "#hasLastName");
OWLDataProperty lastNameProperty = dataFactory.getOWLDataProperty(lastNamePropertyIRI);
List<OWLClassExpression> domainClasses = 
   ontology
      .dataPropertyDomainAxioms(lastNameProperty)
      .map(OWLDataPropertyDomainAxiom::getDomain)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

  for (OWLClassExpression owlClass : domainClasses) {
    logger.trace("Domain class = " + owlClass);
  }
```

However, there are some other problems I am concerned with here which relates to the ontology rather than the code.

For the ontology I have given, whenever you specify that an individual `john` is linked to some surname via `hasLastName`, the ontology reasoner will infer that `john` is **both** a `Person` and a `Student`, i.e. the domain of `hasLastName` is the intersection of `Person` and `Student`. Clearly, this is not true for people in general. There are 2 possible solutions to this, depending on your needs:

(1) You can specify that the domain of `hasLastName` is `Person or Student` which will take the domain to be the union of `Person` and `Student`.

(2) The solution I prefer is to define `Student` as a subclass of `Person` and then to state that the domain of `hasLastName` is the single class `Person`.